# Bigquery: Is it possible to see what jobs caused a high increase in costs?

Tags: google-bigquery, analysis, billing

I have been using BigQuery for a while now, but since this month, one of my projects drastically increased in costs to almost 10 euro's a day. One day it even managed to hit 50 euros. I would like to find out how this project uses 12.54 tebibyte in one week. The SKU is "Analysis" and the service is "BigQuery". How can I find out which queries / jobs are adding the most to this total costs?

I have looked in the Logs Explorer, Monitoring, Billing reports, but could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the answer by myself. For anyone that is wondering as well, here is the query that will give you those costs. (For example for yesterday):

```
SELECT
  query,
  SUM(total_bytes_billed) / POW(10, 12) AS tebi_bytes_billed
FROM
  [project].[region].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS 
WHERE
  EXTRACT(date FROM start_time) = CURRENT_DATE() - 1 
GROUP BY
  query
ORDER BY
  tebi_bytes_billed DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To see which Project is contributing to BigQuery cost you can see that in Reports page and select BigQuery as service and set Group by option to Project. Also to see the consumption you can use Cost Table page in BigQuery billing.

To see the details per query processed use the query - SELECT
creation_time,project_id,job_type,user_email,query,total_bytes_processed,
FROM
region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT

You may also see it by user just use - JOBS_BY_USER and same for organisation.